# Function that loops through a number of records and if a date format is not met store that row in a table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

currently the function is working... tried some approaches

test case is that the column in the db = varchar , thus stores anything.. hence we need to come up witha way to validate that the time format is correct before loading occurs ... if something is inccorect it flags the row example:  using a semi colon to separate time instead of a colon

```
begin 
    for i in (
        select id,time_in 
        from clock_load
        -- where NOT REGEXP_LIKE (replace(time_in,' ',''), '([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]')
    )
    loop
        if to_date(i.time_in,'HH:MI:SS AM') <> TRUE
        then 
            dbms_output.put_line('the row is :' || i.id );
        end if;
                    
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Which database version do you use?

Comment: Using db version 12c up ..currently upgraded to 19c

Answer (score 2):

You can use `to_date` with`on conversion error` in `IF` condition as follows:

```
If to_date(i.time_in default null on conversion error,'HH:MI:SS AM') is null then
```

You can also check if `time_in is not null` as an extra condition if you dont want to consider null values.